# Проблема с open server, ошибка

Tags: openserver

Возникла такая ошибка, у меня есть папка `myServer` в который был установлен сам open server. В папке `domains` у меня хранился один из сайтов. Но после того как я кинул папку `myServer` в другую папку и зашёл в open server, из панели флажок тоже куда-то исчез, когда нажимаю на `Open Server x64.exe` появляется ошибка `Exception EArgumentOutOfRangeException in module Open Server x64.exe at 00000000003DFEA0. Index out of bound.` Буду неимоверно благодарен кто поможет!!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй вернуть папку `MyServers` на исходное положение